# How to cast pandas datetime object to string without index

Tags: pandas, list, datetime, casting

I'm trying to cast a datetime64 panda object to string without printing the index.

I have a csv file with the following

```
Dates
2019-06-01
2019-06-02
2019-06-03
```

When I import the csv file via pandas, I have a normal pandas object in the column.

```
df['Dates'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

This provides a datetime64[ns] object. I tried printing this object with the following output.

```
>>> What is the date 0   2019-06-01
    Name: Dates, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

So I have to cast this object to a string. The documentation suggests I use dt.strftime().

```
s=df["Dates"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print(f"What is the date {s['Dates'}")
```

The output for the above is:

```
>>> What is the date 0  2019-06-01
```

How do I remove the index from the output?

```py
file = r'test.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file)

df['Dates'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'], format='%Y-%m-%d')


s = df[df["Dates"] < "2019-06-02"]
print(f"What is the date {s['Dates']}")

print(s["Dates"])
```

The expected output is the following:

```
>>> What is the date 2019-06-01
```

However I am getting the following

```
>>> What is the date 0  2019-06-01
```

Comment: Try `s.iloc[0,0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
[print(f"What is the date {x}") for x in s['Dates'].astype('str')]
```

gives:

```
What is the date 2019-06-01
What is the date 2019-06-02
What is the date 2019-06-03
```